# In Scala.js, modifying svg.Stylable.style

Tags: svg, scala.js

Working with Scala.js, I have created some SVG elements like `Text`, `Line`, `Rect`, and now I am trying to set the style attribute with code like this, where `element` is of type `svg.Stylable`:

```
element.style.fillOpacity = "0.0"
element.style.stroke = "yellow"
element.style.strokeWidth = "2"
```

I tried different variations of above code, but the desired style does not realize, and when I inspect the element in the Browser, the style attribute is an empty String (""). I am able to set other attributes with no problem (e.g. `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`).

How do I set the style? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For SVG modications in Scala.js I normally use the d3 library (scala.js facade: https://github.com/spaced/scala-js-d3).

Then u can use:

```
d3.select("#mySvgElement").attr("style", "stroke:yellow; stroke-width:2") // etc.
```

*Edit: `mySvgElement` would be the ID of the element i want to change the style for. You can also other different kind of [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors).